# Read exist sqlite - Swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

I have an existing `Sqlite` in my project and I copy it in my device like bellow:

```
func prepareDatabaseFile() /*-> String*/ {
    let fileName: String = "myDB.sqlite"

    let fileManager:FileManager = FileManager.default
    let directory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    let documentUrl = directory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let bundleUrl = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    // here check if file already exists on simulator
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (documentUrl.path)) {
        //Document file exists!
        //return documentUrl.path
    }else if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (bundleUrl?.path)!) {
        //Document file does not exist, copy from bundle!
        try! fileManager.copyItem(at:bundleUrl!, to:documentUrl)
    }
}
```

And I have a `class` with this name `ProjectCoreDataStore` that i get all results from `sqlite` with this `class` like bellow, how can I custom my exist `sqlite` with bellow class for read??

```
class ProjectCoreDataStore: DegreesProtocol, DegreesStoreUtilityProtocol {

    // MARK: - Managed object contexts
    var mainManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    var privateManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext

    // MARK: - Object lifecycle
    init()
    {
        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myDB", withExtension: "momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }

        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }

        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        mainManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        mainManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
        /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
         This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
         */
        let storeURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myDB.sqlite")
        do {
            try psc.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeURL, options: nil)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
        }

        privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateManagedObjectContext.parent = mainManagedObjectContext
    }

    deinit
    {
        do {
            try self.mainManagedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error deinitializing main managed object context")
        }
    }
    func myQuery(){
      ........
    }
}
```

**Problem:**  When I go to path of copy sqlite I see that the sqlite is empty.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here, is the code in `ProjectCoreDataStore` working correctly and you ask about your model or is there an issue with the posted code?

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson. how can I custom my exist sqlite with ProjectCoreDataStore?

Comment: When I go to path of copy sqlite I see that the sqlite is empty.

Comment: I suspect you need also to copy the WAL file. With iOS using Sqlite’s WAL mode, the data is stored in two separate files, the main .sqlite file and a separate .sqlite-wal file.  You need to copy both.

Comment: Is your myDb.sqlite created using Core Data? If it is not you _can not_ use it directly with Core Data and you need to migrate it first. This is what Apple writes about using an existing SQLite database, _You do not, unless you import your existing SQLite database into a Core Data store. Although Core Data supports SQLite as one of its persistent store types, the database format is private. You cannot create a SQLite database using the native SQLite API and use it directly with Core Data. If you have an existing SQLite database, you need to import it into a Core Data store._

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson. I converted my sqlite and fields and table names are start with Z_... Is this true for use in Core Data??